# Call url and get json back in firebase functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hello how can I call a link and receive a json and send it back in the response. I'm new to Firebase functions and typescript.

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
response.send("nope");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use "const" and change as below.

```
export helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return {
            success: true,
            msg: 'this is success message'
        };
});
```

Comment: please explain in detail, what you want ?

Comment: I would like to know how to call a link, this link return a json, which I can send back in the response.